# Why do I have a lot of dead flies on my Euphorbia Tirucalli?

Tags: insects

Last winter as I was taking what I assume is a Euphorbia Tirucalli (unsure) inside, I noticed a large amount of flies clinging to many of the sticks. They were difficult to dislodge and I realized they were all dead. Have I incorrectly identified my plant? What's going on with the flies?

**Edit:**

The plant minus the flies:

[image: Minus the flies]

Comment: What do you mean 'sticks'? Euphorbia has a very toxic sap. Is that what you are seeing?  Yup send pictures...  Is this out of doors or in doors?  How long were these plants in the environment you are talking about?

Comment: Its a small potted set of stems that I bought at a local shop. I looked around for what it could be and came up with Euphorbia Tirucalli as the closest thing I could find. The toxic sap seems to make a lot of sense! I'll keep digging for the pictures!

Comment: Take a picture of your plant as is, that would  be a good beginning.  The flies are attracted for sure, please take pictures because I am just shooting from the hip?  The toxic sap also means do not get this stuff on your skin.  Wear gloves.  Why the heck would a shop  NOT label their stuff correctly?  I would DEMAND more information. They are making a good 75% markup!!

Answer (score -1):

[E. tirucalli as pesticide/medicinal](http://www.tropicallab.ugent.be/thesisjulius.pdf)

I did not know about this stuff, I just assumed based on what I know of Euphorbia.  This article gets into this pesticide characteristic in more detail.  Were you able to to talk to the shop?  Very interesting subject, Alex!